# UDEV: how to match SYMLINK during remove event?

Tags: printing, udev

I am using `libusb` to contact with a printer. And I am writing a rule for `udev` to remove the printer when it is disconnected. I use symlink to indicate the device. But when removing, the rule is not triggered. What should I do?

```
ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Zebra Technologies", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/reinitZebra.sh", SYMLINK+="usblp%k"
SYMLINK=="usblp%k", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/reinitZebra.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

- `%k` (variables) are not to be used in the rule matching condition.

  > **String substitutions**
  >
  > When writing rules which will potentially handle multiple similar devices, udev's printf-like string substitution operators are very useful. You can simply **include these operators in any assignments** your rule makes, and udev will evaluate them when they are executed.

  Source: [Writing udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#strsubst) by Daniel Drake (dsd)
- Use directly same `add` condition (you have chosen a long path):

  ```
  ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Zebra Technologies", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/reinitZebra.sh"
  ```